# bash - combine log files ending with .1 .2 into the original file

Tags: bash, shell

I have log files that ends with `.1` `.2` because there's a size limit.

For example, in my log directory there are files like:
`log20121212`
`log20121212.1`
`log20121212.2`

I want to combine files with the same log date into 1 file, but in the opposite orders. For example, in the combined file, contents of `log20121212.2` should come before contents of `log20121212.1`, contents of `log20121212.1` should come before contents of `log20121212`.

However, files with different dates are combined into separate files. For example, `log20121212.1` should be combined to `log20121212` file, but `log20121213.1` should be combined to `log20121213` file.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Isn't that just a question of altering your logrotate settings?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in $(ls -1 log* | sort -r); do
  cat "$f" >> "${f%.*}.tmp"
done

for f in log*.tmp; do
  mv -f "$f" "${f%.tmp}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to provide the name of the log file:

```
$ ls -1 log20121212.* | sort -t1 -k2 -r
log20121212.4
log20121212.3
log20121212.2
log20121212.1
```

When you want to sort all the log files:

```
$ ls -1 log* | sort -n | sort -t1 -k2 -r
log20121213.2
log20121213.1
log20121212.4
log20121212.3
log20121212.2
log20121212.1
log20121211.2
log20121211.1
```

Comment: There's no real need to call `ls` here. `echo log20121212.* | ...` should work just as well.

Comment: @chepner well, actually it will not work with `echo` (without other changes) because `echo` returns results in one line

Comment: True. `printf "%s\n" log20121212.* | ...` then :)

Answer (score 0):

Modified version of Ansgar Wiechers, which also reverse the order of the lines in each log file (as apparently the idea is to print first the more recent log infos?)

```
ls -1 log* | sort -r | \
while read file ; do
    tac "$file" >> "${file%.*}_out"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested, pure bash solution

```
for f in log*; do
  base="${f%%.*}" # base name for this log, without the .1 part
  >> "${base}-final" # make sure the file exists
  cat "$f" "${base}-final" > tmp # use mktemp to create this file if you want to be secure
  mv tmp "${base}-final"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
shopt -s extglob
tmp=$(mktemp)
for f in log+([0-9]); do
    cat "$f"{.2,.1,} > $tmp && mv $tmp "$f"
done
```